# How to fix not show application icon into app drawer?

Tags: java, android, deep-linking, android-deep-link

In my application i want use **deeplink**. when added `intent-filter` for **deeplink** in **launcher `activity`**, **gone** application icon into app **drawer**!
But when remove **deeplink** `intent-filter` show application icon into app **drawer**.

**Manifest codes :**

```
<activity android:name=".Pages.Splash.SplashPage">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <!-- DeepLink -->
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="www.example.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/gaming"
            android:scheme="http" />
        <data
            android:host="example.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/gaming"
            android:scheme="http" />

    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

when use above codes, not show application icon in app **drawer**, but when remove below codes from `manifest` show icon.

```
        <!-- DeepLink -->
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="www.example.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/gaming"
            android:scheme="http" />
        <data
            android:host="example.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/gaming"
            android:scheme="http" />
```

i want when open users click on link, first start **launcher `activity`**, then dynamically open another `activity`.

How can i fix it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow, Dr. Jake.. I tried hard, to understand what you want to achieve, but failed. Can you explain your intentions clearly what have you implemented and what is the output you're expecting.

Comment: @ChintanSoni, thanks dear. my mean is when use above codes not show me my application icon into app drawer (device applications list). but when remove deeplink codes, show me my application icon. can you help me for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should create two separate intent-filters. Try below code in your `<activity/>` tag:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <!-- DeepLink -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="www.example.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/gaming"
            android:scheme="http" />
        <data
            android:host="example.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/gaming"
            android:scheme="http" />

    </intent-filter>
```

Finally, your code will look as below:

```
<activity android:name=".Pages.Splash.SplashPage">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <!-- DeepLink -->
    <intent-filter>

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="www.example.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/gaming"
            android:scheme="http" />
        <data
            android:host="example.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/gaming"
            android:scheme="http" />

    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```